# GTA 4 "Lagger issue"

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, upgrade

a year ago I had GTA 4 on my laptop, back in then I had 4GB ram and HDD and although I did meet the recommended requirements it was lagging insanely and nothing did help me to fix the performance. Today I have SSD and 8GB ram, but I wanna ask, what does probally cause the lags and if it was caused by my laptop back in then or the game has that bad optimalization. I wanna also say that GTA 5 runs for me on 50 - 80FPS so Im really interested.

Comment: GTA IV was always a unoptimized game and the developers never fixed it, they are still powerful computers that can't run GTA IV. "What does probably cause the lag?" - we can't know the answer.

Comment: So it just like about my luck if it will run fine or not? @CaldeiraG

Comment: There are [some options](https://www.reddit.com/r/GTA/comments/1f3yc9/gta_iv_performance_improving_mod/) you can use to improve the performance of the game.

Comment: @CaldeiraG thank you, but I dont think Itll help coz I already have tried mods and no good.. Ill try this one, thank you sm. Can you post it as answear? Ill give it upvote, Ill not mark it as the final answear coz someone else may know something more about this, if none will, ill mark it as final answear

Comment: Sadly, any answers anyone could submit would be pure speculation and wouldn't really be helpful to somebody else with this problem.  Your question is extremely broad and currently does not contain the required information to explain your performance problems. *An answer that indicates GTA IV is not optimized is not a helpful answer.*

Answer (score 0):

This answer is going to be a generic answer to lag from a basic perspective. The reason for this approach is because how broad the question otherwise is which makes it lean towards being off-topic.

## What is lag?

Lag, or stutter, is when a game does not run smoothly, which causes the gameplay/movement/etc to lag behind. It is a generally accepted term, but there's also a technical term.

In technical terms, lag is a high delay between 2 points on the internet, where low latency is expected, such as during gaming sessions.

A more generally accepted term is visual lag because something is not smooth. This is often the result of a low amount of Frames Per Second (FPS). This answer will deal with the latter (low FPS).

## Low amount of FPS

When the amount of frames on the screen is refreshed less times than the human eye can see, which typically is referred to 25 FPS, the screen will appear more laggy the lower the amount of refreshes are. As a result of low FPS, the brain will have a harder time anticipating on the movement, especially if the FPS value fluctuates or becomes very low.

## What causes a low FPS count, aka lag in games?

There can be many reasons why you get a low FPS count while playing games.

- Keep in mind, that games are demanding programs that do lots of computations in order to give you the game. Both the CPU and the GPU are part of these computations. Where the 3D world is mostly calculated by the GPU, the CPU will calculate the "people" (als known as NPC's, or AI) in the game, as well as other things, such as your movement, where you are, the location and movement of other movable items in the game such as vehicles, etc.
- In addition, your game has many pictures it needs to draw. This requires an imense amount of RAM. Far more than your system has. In order to compensate, it will subsequently load images from your disk. The speed of your RAM and disk are therefor also a factor that can slow down your game. If you have little RAM and your disk can't keep up, the game will slow down.
- Components can become warm. Usualy with CPU and GPU. If they become too warm, the system may throttle them down (make them slower) to prevent hardware damage.
- Software running in the background may cause valuable system resources to be claimed, reducing the performance of your computer.
- Bad game design can cause a game to simply not run well. This can be because the system was developed on very high-end specific systems, and was never properly tested on lower-end systems, or even buggy code that was quickly rushed because the developers had to meet a deadline.
- Settings cranked up too high can also cause for problems. If you ask the pc to calculate everything at ultra high settings, all components have to work really hard to process everything. Setting things on a lower quality, means a lower workload, and thus less likely to hit a bottleneck.

If any of these components hit 100% utilization, the game will reach a maximum speed. At that point, the game cannot go faster. If another component has to wait for something of this item that is running at maximum speed, the other component will slow down too. This is known as a bottleneck. The game slows down due to the slower speed of one of the pc components.

## How to Fix?

It is hard to troubleshoot the above issues in the first place but once you narrow down what the slowdown causes, it usually requires an upgrade or maintenance to figure out if it solves the issue. Keep in mind that there can be more than one bottlenecks. Its just that only one bottleneck will be noticed at a time, because that is the slowest factor.

In this case with GTA: IV, The game was rushed and contains a lot of buggy code that will definitely give performance issues. The other issues are either hardware or software related and require investigation in order to know if this is going to be the problem. Look for the recommended specs of the game vs the minimum specs, and tune your quality settings based on those settings. Still having issues, you probably have a hardware or software bottleneck as described as above.